# Jelly Bean and setBeamPushUris()

Tags: android, nfc, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-beam

I am playing with JB and Beam.
I used the example code giving by android but I filled my uri array like this :

`NfcAdapter m_adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("http://www.effinnov.com")
Uri myuri[] = new Uri[] {uri1};
m_adapter.setBeamPushUris(myuri, this);`

and I get this error :

E/NFC     ( 3101): Uri needs to have either scheme file or scheme content

Can someone give me some advice?

Furthermore i am not sure what to think about that :
"
Android Beam™ now supports large payload transfers over Bluetooth. When you define the data to transfer with either the new setBeamPushUris() method or the new callback interface NfcAdapter.CreateBeamUrisCallback, Android hands off the data transfer to Bluetooth or another alternate transport to achieve faster transfer speeds. This is especially useful for large payloads such as image and audio files and requires no visible pairing between the devices. No additional work is required by your app to take advantage of transfers over Bluetooth.
"

=> does it means that transfer do not use NFC anymore? or it uses NFC it contents is small and bluetooth oterwise?

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone give me some advice?

You can beam local files. You cannot beam the contents of Web pages directly from an `http://` URL.

> does it means that transfer do not use NFC anymore?

AFAIK, it will not use NFC for beamed content, where by "beamed" I mean stuff like `setBeamPushUris()`. The NFC radio is used to initiate the transfer, including setting up the Bluetooth connection. NFC is also used for non-beam scenarios, such as reading an NFC tag.

Comment: So if i understand it well, when using setBeamPushUris() NFC radio only initiate the blutooth transfer so it differs from setNdefPushMessage() where the whole transfer is done by NFC radio.

Comment: @Luciflore: Correct. `setNdefPushMessage()` and `setNdefPushMessageCallback()` also limit you to NDEF messages, not arbitrary files.